# answering/asking SO questions from emacs.?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Right now I am using `gnus` to read SO questions by subscribing interested tags from gwene. 
I can only see/read the Question and not the answers.

Is there a plugin to answer/ask SO question. Of course I can use edit-server to compose the messages from QA.

But I want to know is there any way to bring all the things to emacs foothold.

PS: I hope this question will not be moved to `meta` for discussion Since it relates more of programming in elisp

UPDATE: is there any other slimier sort of thing exists for other editors/IDEs/something_else ??

Comment: It's doable. I'm almost completely certain such a thing doesn't exist, but this is a great idea for a project.

Comment: Are you looking for something other than a [generic emacs-integrated browser](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryWebBrowser)?

Comment: @RafeKettler Thanks for letting me know its not available, I guessed that.

Comment: @sarnold not really, even though I thought of checking out xwidget, I am looking more like a plugin which can hook up SO api

Comment: related: http://psung.blogspot.com/2010/01/edit-with-emacs-chrome-extension.html

Comment: There is [Weboob](http://symlink.me/projects/weboob) which does this thing for some french websites but not SO. Since it uses python to make the backends it shouldn't be hard for some guys around there to code a backend for SO. You can then use the capabilities of a backend to receive and send messages with a dedicated interface or with a mail client, or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

I asked a similar question on Meta stack: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116521/authenticating-self-using-stackoverflow-api

StackOverflow API Version 1.0+ does not support these functions.

The 2.0 Version intends to include features allowing us to authenticate/sign-on and interact view the API.

This link (from the Meta question) will take you to the 2.0 API Private Beta site.

https://stackapps.com/questions/2701/api-v2-private-beta-begins

That should make the answer more definitive.